# Django-cms Placeholderfield not working, throws lambda exception

Tags: python, lambda, django-templates, typeerror, django-cms

I wrote a custom plugin on django-cms and added a placeholderfield. Once added that plugin on a placeholder, I try to add using frontend-editing a plugin inside the placeholderfield and it throws:

**On frontend-editing**

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)     
http://localhost:8000/es/admin/cms/page/add-plugin/
```

**On console appears**

```
"POST /es/admin/cms/page/add-plugin/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1620
```

**When I try to edit the custom plugin placed in a page using the admin interface or frontend-editing**

```
TypeError at /es/admin/cms/page/4/edit-plugin/14/
<lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/es/admin/cms/page/4/edit-plugin/14/
Django Version: 1.5.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
<lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
Exception Location: /home/ed/Envs/django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/forms/widgets.py in render, line 201
Python Executable:  /home/ed/Envs/django/mh/../bin/python
```

**My plugin's code looks like this**

**Models.py**

```
from cms.models.pluginmodel import CMSPlugin
from cms.models.fields import PlaceholderField
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Item(CMSPlugin):
title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="Item Name",verbose_name=u'Titulo')
description = PlaceholderField('Item_Description')
image = models.ImageField(upload_to="uploads/images/",verbose_name=u'Imagen')
imageDescription = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="Image",verbose_name=u'Descripcion de la imagen')
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from cms.admin.placeholderadmin import PlaceholderAdmin
from projects.models import Item

admin.site.register(Item, PlaceholderAdmin)
```

**cms_plugins.py**

```
from cms.plugin_base import CMSPluginBase
from cms.plugin_pool import plugin_pool
from cms.models.pluginmodel import CMSPlugin
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from models import Item

class ItemPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    model = Item
    name = "Item Plugin"
    render_template = "item_plugin.html"
    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context['instance'] = instance
        return context

#Registers the plugin
plugin_pool.register_plugin(ItemPlugin)
```

**VERSIONS**

I'm currently using

```
Django-cms: 2.2 
Django: 1.5.1
Linux: 12.04 LTS
```

Please I want to know how to place a plugin inside placeholderfield whitout that annoying error. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

ItemPlugin needs to have the magic from PlaceholderAdmin. Try this:

```
from cms.admin.placeholderadmin import PlaceholderAdmin
...
class ItemPlugin(CMSPluginBase, PlaceholderAdmin):
...
```

Comment: Fixed it for me, thanks! Why the heck isn't that in the documentation...?

Answer (score 0):

django CMS 2.2 does not support Django 1.5 [1].

If you need Django 1.5, please upgrade to the latest 2.4 release.

[1] http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.2/getting_started/installation.html#requirements